# Splitting units base of a number and separating remainders

Tags: java, if-statement, math, radix, operation

I am trying to split a number of a base then separating the two numbers to get different outputs. (Keep in mind I just edited, my answer is the solution). This is left here so people that have a similar problem can find a solution. Thank you all!

So this is the idea:

If number >= 10 && of base 10

Then give me discounted price on 10 units

if number <= 0 && not base 10

Then add the discount for the number which has 10 units in it and the remainder without the discount (let's say 100% for simplicity sake of the numbers)

So to make a practical example
If I order 25 units of x (at $1 each) and 15 units (at $1 each) of y the price will be:

x 20 units = $0
x 5 units = $5 total

y 10 units = $0
y 5 units = $5 total

This is a bit tricky and this is what I got so far:

```
double discountedmNI = (mNI - ((mNI/100)*10)) * mNIC;
double discountedmNIP = mNI - ((mNI/100)*10);

if(mNIC >= 10 && mNIC % 10 == 0){

    System.out.println("mNI " + discountedmNIP + " " + mNIC);
    System.out.println(discountedmNI);

}

else if (!mNIC % 10 == 0){

    System.out.println("mNI " + mNI + mNIC);
    System.out.println(mNI * mNIC);

}
```

I don't think I am defining separate the 10 units right

Thank you all!

Comment: The negation of `If number >= 10 && of base 10` is `If number < 10 || not base 10`.

Comment: Well I guess I should change the tile, it's not really a negation but, my answer is the answer, I am just waiting 2 days to acknowledge it, because it worked

Comment: I admit not really trying to understand the issue.  mNI must be a double too, as with int it would have and int division, likely to become 0. And in financial software BigDecimal is preferable over double, as double has no fixed precision and approximates numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EUREKA!

```
    double discountedmNIP = mNI - ((mNI/100)*10);
    int mNIC2 = (mNIC % 10);
    double mNIC2disc = (mNI * mNIC2);
    double discountedmNI = (mNI - ((mNI/100)*10)) * (mNIC - mNIC2);


    if(mNIC >= 10){

        System.out.println(discountedmNIP + " " + (mNIC - mNIC2) + " " + discountedmNI );
        System.out.println(mNI + " " + mNIC2 + " " + mNIC2disc);

    }



    else{

        System.out.print(mNI + " " + mNIC);
        System.out.print(mNI * mNIC);


    }

    double sum = (mNI + discountedmNI + discountedRh + rH);

    System.out.println('\t');
    System.out.println("Total order cost " + sum);
```

All I need to do is to take the units % 10 which will divide the left side integer or double by the right side (left side input from user)

and will give me the remainder when I do that variable subtracted to the original variable!

Again, this small step took me a whole night to figure it out, and is simple indeed. This is for a class, and if you are in that class and you are reading (even though you might have to dig a little to find what assignment is this one), I would just like to tell you this is what's fun about programming! I am not being sarcastic I really love these type of problems!

Signed:

That foreign guy;

EUREKA again!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right. I get that you want to calculate a total price that consists of two elements: the price for non-discounted items and a price for discounted items.

```
// The following three values are just example assumptions.
float discountInPercent = 100.0f;
float itemsOrdered = 5004.0f;
float itemPriceNormal = 5.0f;

// Here the price for one discounted item gets calculated.
// Please remember that the discount is given in percentage.
float itemPriceDiscounted = itemPriceNormal * ((100.0f - discountInPercent) / 100.0f);

// Calculate the count of items that get discounted and those that 
// will get priced normally.
float itemsDiscounted = Math.floor(itemsOrdered / 10.0f);
float itemsNotDiscounted = itemsOrdered % 10;

// Finally calculate the two elements of the total price and sum it up. 
float priceDiscounted = (itemsDiscounted * itemPriceDiscounted);
float priceNormal = (itemsNotDiscounted * itemPriceNormal);
float totalPrice = priceDiscounted + priceNormal;

System.out.println("Price discounted: %.2f" + priceDiscounted);
System.out.println("Price non-discounted: %.2f" + priceNormal);
System.out.println("Price total: %.2f" + totalPrice);
```

Comment: No not really sorry it's my bad I am confusing here is kinda of an example:      

item x
item y

if item x is >= 10

then take the 10 units and apply the discount on what is only 10 units

The remainder units do not

So if I buy 25 units of x

I will have the discount on 20 units

But on the remainder 5 units I will pay full price

do same with item y

Sorry it's kinda of a dozy

Comment: Thank you I found it, if you are curious check it out!